# Making an automated chessboard

Tags: computer-vision, hall-sensor

I want to create an automated chessboard. At the moment, I'm making the project and deciding what technology to use to detect which piece is at what position and how to move them. I'm not so skilled in eletronics so I'm reading online and trying to find an efficient and cost-friendly solution.

I read about reed switches, but these only detect if a piece is in a position, without telling which piece is it. The same goes for hall effect sensors. Then I thought about using computer vision, but placing a camera on top of everything would be bulky.

So a nice idea could be using rfid tags under every piece. Also magnets have to be placed to move the pieces and small leds to show the possible moves in the board. Magnetic field could be a problem.

I wanted to ask, if this idea could work from an eletronic aspect, and if there are other technologies to be used.

Thank you.

Comment: make chessboard transparent ... XY gantry underneath ... gantry contains a magnet for moving pieces and a camera for reading barcode on bottom of pieces ... every square has a presence sensor

Comment: ok thank you very much, however this will make the game not so aestetich. I think i won't implement the possibility to recognise the type of chess piece

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Mukund, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: To that end all the ways that you have suggested could be made to work. But as you have mentioned there will be tradeoffs of all the decisions.